# Pillow library quantize not working on my raspberry pi4b

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4

Code basically grayscale, pixelize and resize to a 32x32 format, everything works except when i put in the code in line 11 which limits the picture to 8 shades of grey. This causes the code to come up with the error "ValueError: Conversion not supported"

```
# Tested on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
# Huats Club 2022 for the Pixel-Tint Project
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
#from student_pub import *

## open image file
myImage = Image.open('Pixelizer/pokeball.png')
myImage.show()

## greyscale image file
greyImage = ImageOps.grayscale(myImage)
#greyImage.show()

## Limiting to 8 shades of greyscale colour
greyQuantize = greyImage.quantize(8)
#greyQuantize.show()

## resize to 32 x 32 pixels
smallImage = greyQuantize.resize((32,32), Image.BILINEAR)
#smallImage.show()

## Blow it back up to original photo size (32 x 32 pixels upscale)
resultImage = smallImage.resize(myImage.size, Image.NEAREST)
resultImage.show()

## Write Image to save .png file
#resultImage.save('cartoon.png')

# Retrieving pixel value and formating it into list of list
x = 32; k = 0; outputValue = [0 for i in range(x)]
for i in range(x):
    outputValue[i] = [0 for j in range(x)]
pixValue = list(smallImage.getdata())

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(x):
        outputValue[i][j] = pixValue[k]
        k = k + 1;

print(outputValue)
#pubpic(outputValue)
```

the code works fine without the greyQuantize = greyImage.quantize(8) and im new so i dont really know how to fix this problem. The code is running on my pi raspberry 4b with python 3.7.3 using the thonny python ide editor. u can put in your own pictures on line 7 just list the directory and image file such as 'folder/file.png'

Comment: What is `greyImage.mode`?

Comment: Your code runs fine under PIL v9.1

Comment: There's a very similar example here for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338520/2836621

Comment: @MarkRansom i dont think the code has a greyImage.mode so i dont really know as well

Comment: Every PIL image has a `.mode` attribute.  I'm asking you to look up what it is in your code.  If you can't do the simplest thing how do you expect any help?

Comment: You just need to do `print(greyImage.mode)` after you create `greyImage`.